# DetailsView change text to a label on ItemInserted event

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, detailsview

I have label within a DetailsView.
I need to change Text property of this Label inside the DetailsView after event ItemInserted has been trigged.

Script does not throws any error, but the Label does not change its text property.
Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for your time!

Markup:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="uxInsertAuthorInput" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False"
        DataKeyNames="AuthorId" DataSourceID="EntityDataSourceCreateAuthor" DefaultMode="Insert"
        OnItemInserting="uxInsertAuthor_ItemInserting" OnItemInserted="uxInsertAuthorInput_ItemInserted">
    <Fields>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="FirstName">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="uxFirstNameDisplayer" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="uxFirstNameInput" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>' />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="uxRequiredFieldValidatorFirstName" runat="server"
                    ControlToValidate="uxFirstNameInput" ErrorMessage="First Name Field is required">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="LastName">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="uxLastNameDisplayer" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="uxLastNameInput" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>' />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="uxRequiredFieldValidatorLastName" runat="server"
                    ControlToValidate="uxLastNameInput" ErrorMessage="Last Name Field is required">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UserId" SortExpression="UserId">
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="uxUserListSelector" runat="server" />
                <asp:Label ID="uxAllert" runat="server" Text="Label" />
            </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Profile" SortExpression="ContentAuthor">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="uxContentAuthorDisplayer" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ContentAuthor") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="uxContentAuthorInput" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ContentAuthor") %>' />
            </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NoteInternal" SortExpression="NoteInternal">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="uxNoteInternalDisplayer" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NoteInternal") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="uxNoteInternalInput" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NoteInternal") %>' />
            </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="True" />
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void uxInsertAuthorInput_ItemInserted(object sender, DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs e)
{
    String FirstName = e.Values["FirstName"].ToString();
    String LastName = e.Values["LastName"].ToString();
    uxMessageDisplayer.Text = string.Format("Author: {0} {1} has been added.", FirstName, LastName);

    // problem is here:
    Label myAllert = (Label)uxInsertAuthorInput.FindControl("uxAllert");
    myAllert.Text = "TEST";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `ItemUpdated` event of detailsview rather than `ItemInserted` event

**ItemUpdated:** Occurs when an Update button within a DetailsView control is clicked, but after the update operation. from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview_events.aspx)

I am sure this will resolve issue 100%

Comment: Thanks, I found out the solution: it is working with _ItemCreated also thanks for your help